# Textbox TextMode is Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, webforms

i try retrive data from db-(sql-server) but im can't fill textbox becusee

TextMode = "Date"

my field in db is DateTime

```
string transDate = dr["TransDate"].ToString();
txtTransDate.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dr["TransDate"].ToString());


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTransDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"
                                            CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: im can't fill textbox because my textbox mode is Date

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtTransDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"
                                            CssClass="form-control"
                                            onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event)"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: im use (DataRow dr)

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
var date=DateTime.Parse(dr["TransDate"].ToString());
txtTransDate.Text=date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy);
```