# Textbox Mode Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-frontend

i try retrive data from db-(sql-server) but im can't fill textbox becusee

TextMode = "Date"

my field in db is DateTime

```
DataTable dt=ED_Data.Fill_Dis_SupDates();
DataRow dr=dt.Rows[0];

    string transDate = dr["TransDate"].ToString();
    txtTransDate.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dr["TransDate"].ToString());



<asp:TextBox ID="txtTransDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What's the issue with this code? Are you getting any error? Is textbox not displaying the date? How it is displaying? How it should display? Why are you asking the same question again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648321/textbox-textmode-is-date

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this not work im can't fill textbox

Comment: im need to hel how i can solve this problem im using in asp.net webform textbox have properity name "TextMode" im choies "Date" .... for here good , my problem is when im retrive date textbox of date not fill im don't know why not run

Comment: u understand me now???

Answer (score 0):

TextMode="Date" does not change the data type return by the textbox it will always return string.

Try this:

```
DataTable dt=ED_Data.Fill_Dis_SupDates();
DataRow dr=dt.Rows[0];

txtTransDate.Text =Convert.ToDateTime( dr["TransDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Case one lands here in Future:

i. Ensure your output from the Database is in the Format yyyy-MM-dd (This format is a MUST for it to work in the textbox)
ii. Assign this output directly to the textbox e.g.
txtStartDate.Text = yourDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateStart"].ToString();